# Recording with remote I/O, AudioUnitRender -50 return code

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audiounit

I've been working on a frequency detection application for iOS and I'm having an issue filling a user-defined AudioBufferList with audio samples from the microphone.

I'm getting a return code of -50 when I call AudioUnitRender in my InputCallback method. I believe this means one of my parameters is invalid. I'm guessing it's the AudioBufferList, but I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong with it. I think I've set it up so it matches the data format I've specified in my ASBD.

Below is the remote I/O setup and function calls that I believe could be incorrect:

ASBD:

```
size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType);
AudioStreamBasicDescription localStreamFormat = {0};
localStreamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
localStreamFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
localStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = bytesPerSample;
localStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = bytesPerSample;
localStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
localStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * bytesPerSample;
localStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
localStreamFormat.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
```

InputCallback Declaration:

```
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(ioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                           kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                           kOutputBus, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct));
```

AudioBufferList Declaration:

```
// Allocate AudioBuffers
bufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBuffer));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 2;

bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = 1024;
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData = calloc(256, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

InputCallback Function:

```
AudioUnit rioUnit = THIS->ioUnit;
OSStatus renderErr;
UInt32 bus1 = 1;
renderErr = AudioUnitRender(rioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, bus1, inNumberFrames, THIS->bufferList);
```

A few things to note:

- Sample Rate = 22050 Hz
- Since the canonical format of remote I/O data is 8.24-bit fixed point, I'm assuming the samples are 32 bits each (or 4 bytes). Since an unsigned int is 4 bytes, I'm using that to allocate my audio buffer.
- I can get the same code to render audio correctly if I implement the audio data flow as PassThru rather than input only.
- I've already looked at [Michael Tyson's blog post](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) on Remote I/O. Didn't see anything there different from what I'm doing.

Thanks again, you all are awesome!

Demetri

Comment: I finally finished the frequency detection application I mentioned. I've posted a write-up along with the source code for those interested. EDIT: the link...http://sleepyleaf.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/

Comment: No Code has been found in mentioned.. Links sleepyleaf.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x –  irtemed88

Comment: Oops sorry, I updated my domain. New link: http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/

Comment: Link : http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/ is not working. If you still have a code, you can add it to github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have 2 channels per frame, you cannot have `bytesPerSample` as the size of the frame.  Since the terminology is a bit confusing:

- A **sample** is a single value at a given position in a waveform
- A **channel** refers to data associated with a particular audio stream, ie, left/right channel for stereo, a single channel for mono, etc.
- A **frame** contains the samples for all channels for a given position in a waveform
- A **packet** contains one or more frames

So basically, you need to use `bytesPerSample * mChannelsPerFrame` for `mBytesPerFrame`, and use `mBytesPerFrame * mFramesPerPacket` for `mBytesPerPacket`.

Also I noticed that you are using 32-bits for your sample size.  I'm not sure if you really want to do this -- usually, you want to record audio using 16-bit samples.  The sound difference between 16 and 32 bit audio is almost impossible for most listeners to hear (the average CD is mastered at 44.1kHz, 16-bit PCM), and it will spare you 50% of the I/O and storage costs.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was a little confused because the documentation states the canonical audio sample format is 8.24-bit fixed-point. I assumed that was the format I had to use and it was 32-bits. If I'm using 16-bit samples, does that mean the sample types are 16-bit signed ints?

Comment: Yes, 16-bit would mean that your data is technically stored as signed shorts, or `SInt16`. And yes, while 8-24 bit does represent the most common range, almost all everyday recording stuff uses 16 bit.  8 bit sounds terrible, and nobody can hear the difference between 16 and 24. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that Tyson's RemoteIO blog post uses 2 bytes per sample of linear PCM.  So this might be a format incompatible error.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be a problem since I've set kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical for the format flags. The documentation indicates this is 8.24-bit fixed-point format.

Answer (score 0):

The line `bufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBuffer));` is also wrong. Since AudioBuffer is smaller than AudioBufferList, it allocates not enough memory.